# azure VM with windows server

Tags: azure

I have an azure VM running windows. I have used it some time for testing and then let it unused.
Now I try to log in again. At first I couldn't. I restarted my machine from azure portal.

I logged in (RDP) but after 5 minutes and while I was doing something (I mean it wasn't inactive) it closed the connection. I tried to connect again with no success.

I restarted again and logged in. Again the same thing. After some minutes it drops the connection.

Any help? I cannot find anything from azure diagnostics or event viewer in server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if the VM is running in the portal or see the screenshots of the VM status in the virtual machine --- Support + troubleshooting --- Boot diagnostics.

When this issue occurs, check if you are able to [telnet](http://blog.industrialnetworking.com/2011/09/using-telnet-to-test-open-ports.html) or [PSPing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2014/06/22/use-port-pings-instead-of-icmp-to-test-azure-vm-connectivity/) into VM to ensure that the VM is able to connect to the Network. If you can not telnet or PSPing with RDP port. It clarifies that the network connectivity is broken. You can try to turn the firewall off or check the NSG with Azure VM or its subnet.

Try to connect to VM from a different domain or network. Check if the same issue happens.

If the issue still exists after the above steps, you can try to [resize your VM.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/resize-virtual-machines/). This will move VM to another node.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 4 minutes limit on TCP connections in Azure. You wrote that the server wasn't inactive but if your RDP session is inactive the connection will be closed. You can test this if you change the 4 minutes limit to someting else(max 30 min).

```
Set-AzurePublicIP -PublicIPName webip -VM MyVM -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 15
```

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-tcp-idle-timeout

Comment: I use the RDP in those 3-4 minutes. I am searching thins on the VM so RDP is not inactive also. Besides I cannot reconnect with RDP after this. I need to restart the server

Comment: After the disconnect when you can't connect, do you have the same issue if you download a new RDP file(connect via the portal)?

Comment: yes. I get RDP disconnected!
516 Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:

1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
2) The remote computer is turned off
3) The remote computer is not available on the network

Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled

Comment: @gong you can try it with the firewall off.

Comment: I have no firewall on machine. Only the firewall provided from azure, which has RDP port open

Comment: You really got a weird error, have you tried the "Azure VM universal fix" and redploy the VM? ( https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/updates/use-azure-redeploy-functionality-to-transfer-virtual-machines-to-a-new-host/ ) .

Comment: @gong what about the firewall locally instead of Azure VM? Have you tried to connect to VM from a different network?

Comment: no I couldn't find time to do it. Anyway the VM was used for a test setup. Maybe I will re-deploy and loose all files and setups in the VM. thanks